# How to make HTTP stream from RTSP

Tags: http, terminal, rtsp, openalpr

I have LRP camera which produces RTSP stream in `rtsp://172.16.4.6`. I use `VLC` to see this streaming. Then I need to use `ALPR Daemon` for passing stream in `http://` to recognize registration plates captured by camera. According to documentation in should be only `http://`. So using `VLC` I am trying to convert/transcode it to proper format. What is the problem, that I am not familiar with this field and have no time to study basic.

I installed `apache2` on `ubuntu` that has `port 80` and `http://127.0.0.1` address. Then I tried to use some of approaches from documentation https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/ , then I tried `$vlc -I http rtsp://172.16.4.6:554/HighResolutionVideo :sout='#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,vb=800,fps=5}:std{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-repace},mux=mpjpeg,dst=127.0.0.1:80/go.mjpg,delay=0}'`

But then I have this error log:

```
 [00007f5fb0001268] core access out error: socket bind error: Permission denied
 [00007f5fb0001268] core access out error: cannot create socket(s) for HTTP host
 [00007f5fb0001268] access_output_http access out error: cannot start HTTP server
 [00007f5fb0003388] stream_out_standard stream out error: no suitable sout access module for `http{mine=multipart/x-mixed-repace}/mpjpeg://172.0.0.1:80/go.mjpg'
 [00007f5fb0000b18] core stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{vcodec=MJPG,vb=800,fps=5}:std{access=http{mine=multipart/x-mixed-repace},mux=mpjpeg,dst=172.0.0.1:80/go.mjpg,delay=0}'
 [00007f5fb42929f8] core input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
 [00007f5fb0003388] access_output_http access out: Consider passing --http-host=IP on the command line instead.
 [00007f5fb0003388] core access out error: socket bind error: Permission denied
 [00007f5fb0003388] core access out error: cannot create socket(s) for HTTP host
 [00007f5fb0003388] access_output_http access out error: cannot start HTTP server
 [00007f5fb0001268] stream_out_standard stream out error: no suitable sout access module for `http{mine=multipart/x-mixed-repace}/mpjpeg://172.0.0.1:80/go.mjpg'
 [00007f5fb0000b18] core stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{vcodec=MJPG,vb=800,fps=5}:std{access=http{mine=multipart/x-mixed-repace},mux=mpjpeg,dst=172.0.0.1:80/go.mjpg,delay=0}'
 [00007f5fb42929f8] core input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in `repace`, Try this:

```
--sout #transcode{vcodec=MJPG,venc=ffmpeg{strict=1}}:standard{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=:80/go.mjpg}
```